# How to copy cudaArray between two GPUs directly?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpu

Suppose I have a cudaArray in GPU1 and another cudaArray in GPU2.

Calling cudaMemcpyArrayToArray with a cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice flag actually results in GPU1 cudaArray copied to host memory and host memory copied to GPU2 cudaArray by looking at the profiler.

I tried copying the GPU1 cudaArray to a GPU1 global memory and call cudaMemcpyPeer to copy to a GPU2 global memory and then copy it to the GPU2 cudaArray. This is better than going through the host memory but there are still a lot of redundant copying.

Why isn't there a cudaMemcpyPeerArrayToArray? How do I copy cudaArray between two GPUs directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a peer to peer API for CUDA arrays.

Use either [cudaMemcpy3DPeer](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1geeab4601354962a5968eefc8b79ec2dd) or 
[cudaMemcpy3DPeerAsync](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g7386b2845149b48c87f82ea017690aa8). This will use the most optimal device to device transfer path from within the peer to peer options available on your system.

Comment: I browsed through this API before but didn't notice that the cudaArray is hidden in the struct... thanks a lot for the pointer

Comment: But is this path typically direct? Or does it go through device memory? (Say, in Maxwell GPUs)

Comment: @einpoklum: I don't understand what you are asking. what is "direct" and what is "through device memory" in this context?

Comment: I mean, does the contents of the array have to be written somewhere in device memory, from where it is actually sent to another GPU, or can it go directly out to the PCI bus?

Comment: @einpoklum: still don't understand what you are asking. This is, by definition, a device to device memory transfer. The source data is in one GPUs memory and will be copied to another. But CUDA peer to peer transfers are not supported on PCI devices anyway (do they even make those anymore?) It requires features of the PCI-e v2.0 specification